# Create vertical 2D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
first_name = [["Tom", "Alex", "Sam"], ["Anna", "Bob", "Mike"]] 
last_name = [["Smith", "Brown", "Lee"], ["Davis", "Allen", "Lewis"]]
```

I want to create a ****vertical** numpy array**, where the output is like the following:

```
[["Tom Smith"    "Anna Davis"]
 ["Alex Brown"   "Bob Allen"]
 ["Sam Lee"     "Mike Lewis"]]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: After working through some alternatives, I recall a similar comparison in another recent SO.  Maybe someone can find that and mark this as duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = np.array([[f'{c} {d}' for c, d in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(first_name, last_name)]).T
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['Tom Smith' 'Anna Davis']
 ['Alex Brown' 'Bob Allen']
 ['Sam Lee' 'Mike Lewis']]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a double list comprehension we can join all pairs:

```
In [4]: [' '.join([k,l]) for i,j in zip(first_name, last_name) for k,l in zip(i,j)]
Out[4]: ['Tom Smith', 'Alex Brown', 'Sam Lee', 'Anna Davis', 'Bob Allen', 'Mike Lewis']
```

But you wanted nested lists:

```
In [5]: [[' '.join([k,l]) for k,l in zip(i,j)] for i,j in zip(first_name, last_name)]
Out[5]: 
[['Tom Smith', 'Alex Brown', 'Sam Lee'],
 ['Anna Davis', 'Bob Allen', 'Mike Lewis']]
```

The order is wrong, so we can apply a list equivalent of a transpose:

```
In [6]: list(zip(*_))
Out[6]: 
[('Tom Smith', 'Anna Davis'),
 ('Alex Brown', 'Bob Allen'),
 ('Sam Lee', 'Mike Lewis')]
```

I haven't worked out a way of moving that 'transpose' into the double loop.

`numpy` has some `np.char` functions that apply string methods to elements of arrays.

```
In [24]: np.char.add(np.char.add(first_name, ' '),last_name).T
Out[24]: 
array([['Tom Smith', 'Anna Davis'],
       ['Alex Brown', 'Bob Allen'],
       ['Sam Lee', 'Mike Lewis']], dtype='<U10')
```

Here I use `np.char.add` to add elements of two arrays (or lists turned into arrays).  I have to first add a space to one array, and then add the other.  As before we need a transpose.

This actually looks simpler, but I not sure it's any faster.

Or by making object dtype arrays, we can use the '+' operator:

```
In [27]: (np.array(first_name, object)+np.array(' ',object)+np.array(last_name,object)).T
Out[27]: 
array([['Tom Smith', 'Anna Davis'],
       ['Alex Brown', 'Bob Allen'],
       ['Sam Lee', 'Mike Lewis']], dtype=object)
```

The list comprehension times the fastest, but times from a small example like this have to taken with caution.  The different approaches may scale differently.

```
In [31]: timeit list(zip(*[[' '.join([k,l]) for k,l in zip(i,j)] for i,j in zip(
    ...: first_name, last_name)]))
4.17 µs ± 142 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [32]: timeit np.char.add(np.char.add(first_name, ' '),last_name).T
39.5 µs ± 780 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [33]: timeit (np.array(first_name, object)+np.array(' ',object)+np.array(last
    ...: _name,object)).T
9.74 µs ± 60.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```